# React Datepicker - wrong date showing when I bind to enable e.preventDefault()

Tags: reactjs, forms, datepicker, bind

Datepicker is detecting the correct date but the form is refreshing.

So, I inserted e.preventDefault() into the function.

This gave me an error saying e.preventDefault() is not a function.

So I changed the function to use bind

```
onChange={(event)=> this.changeStartDetails.bind(this)}
```

But now, no matter what date I select, datePicker registers it as today at midnight.

Where am I going wrong?

The full code is here

Summary code is below:

```
  constructor(){
        super()
        this.changeStartDetails= this.changeStartDetails.bind(this)
        } 

changeStartDetails(e){

   e.preventDefault()

    console.log('e', e)
    console.log('moment(e)', moment(e).format('DD MM YY HH:mm'))
    console.log('moment()', moment().format('DD MM YY HH:mm'));
    console.log('!moment(e).isAfter(moment())', !moment(e).isAfter(moment()));
}

   <form>

            <DatePicker
                className="datePicker"
                timeIntervals={15}
                selected={this.state.startDetails}
                onChange={(event)=> this.changeStartDetails.bind(this)}
                showTimeSelect
                dateFormat="d MMM yyyy HH:mm"
                required
                placeholderText={'Date & Time Event Starts'}
            />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistaken here,

```
onChange={(event)=> this.changeStartDetails.bind(this)}
```

Your mistakenly binding your event listener in AND also calling in callback function.

You probably meant something like this,

```
onChange={this.changeStartDetails.bind(this)}
```

Or,

```
onChange={event => this.changeStartDetails(event)}
```

EDIT:
in this test everything worked, there wasn't any form refreshing also.

```
function App() {
    const [sdate, setSDate] = useState(new Date());
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <DatePicker
                className="datePicker"
                timeIntervals={15}
                selected={sdate}
                onChange={(event) => {
                    console.log('onChange', event);
                    setSDate(event);
                }}
                showTimeSelect
                dateFormat="d MMM yyyy HH:mm"
                required
                placeholderText={'Date & Time Event Starts'}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I'm getting error of 'TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function' for both of these

Comment: @Colfah whats the `datePicker` ?

Comment: <a href="https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker" target="_blank">this package</a>

Comment: @Colfah weird, i dont see any form submition going on

Comment: I'm in a child component if that makes any difference. Testing it in parent component now. Must be a bug somewhere as the datePicker component is surely used in forms all the time

Comment: Yes, the problem isn't as a result of the form. It was behaving as if the form had refreshed....it detected the date selected but then immediately re-ran and detected the date as today at midnight. I re-wrote the function and its working now. Looks identical to previous function so at a loss to understand what the problem was. Thanks for your help

Comment: The problem was that I also had an onBlur function triggering. I removed it from the code for stackoverflow to simplify!